# Where do I ask questions about Visual Studio?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If I have questions about the visual studio interface, or errors, or stuff like that, should I ask on StackOverflow, meta, or some other site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On StackOverflow (There are lots of Visual Studio tags to target the specific version and sometimes the specific feature you are looking to ask about.)